# Do we know why GAN-based data augmentation works?

Tags: neural-network, gan, data-augmentation

Although I've seen many examples of GAN-generated synthetic data greatly improving the performance of models, I struggle to understand how this is possible.

Say we are training a classifier $h$ to predict distribution $D$ based on dataset $X$, and we use GAN $g$ to augment our dataset, creating $X' | X \subset X'$.

$g$ has the same input as $h$; therefore, it has the same amount of total information and can still only reliably estimate the subset of $D$ which contains $X$. $g$ may "create" more data, but its accuracy is far from guaranteed.

Why does this work?

If the composition of neural networks $h(g(X))$ is better, shouldn't we theoretically be able to create a single neural network $h'$ that is as resourceful as $g$ but serves the purpose of $h$?

Comment: it is possible to create a network $h'$. One can even say that this **is** that network (ie $h+g$)

Comment: @NikosM. thanks for your comment. Shouldn't we be able to skip the intermediary step of augmentation with a model that is more data efficient? In other words, does the performance of $h+g$ demonstrate a weakness in our understanding of model training? Augmentation in general just seems like a temporary solution. For example CNNs should be translation/scale invariant, but random translation/scale remain key elements of many data augmentation pipelines.

Comment: Whether there is an alternative network $h'$ with similar performance, does not exclude the fact that $h+g$ also satisfies these criteria.